# generalized java service using hibernate envers to audit changes done by user in database in web application

Tags: spring, hibernate, aop, cdc

```
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {

            //test insert
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
        System.out.println("Maven + Hibernate + MySQL");
       // Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

        //session.beginTransaction();
        Stock stock = new Stock();

        stock.setStockCode("7000");
        stock.setStockName("z");

        session.saveOrUpdate(stock);

}

Stock.java

import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;
import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;

import com.warp.intercept.*;

/**
* Stock generated by hbm2java
*/

@Entity
@Table(name = "stock", catalog = "mkyong", uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "STOCK_NAME"),
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "STOCK_CODE") })
public class Stock implements java.io.Serializable, IAuditLog {

    private Integer stockId;
    private String stockCode;
    private String stockName;

    public Stock() {
    }

    public Stock(String stockCode, String stockName) {
        this.stockCode = stockCode;
        this.stockName = stockName;
    }


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "STOCK_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getStockId() {
        return this.stockId;
    }

    public void setStockId(Integer stockId) {
        this.stockId = stockId;
    }

    @Column(name = "STOCK_CODE", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 10)
    public String getStockCode() {
        return this.stockCode;
    }

    public void setStockCode(String stockCode) {
        this.stockCode = stockCode;
    }

    @Column(name = "STOCK_NAME", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 20)
    public String getStockName() {
        return this.stockName;
    }

    public void setStockName(String stockName) {
        this.stockName = stockName;
    }
```

I have a java web application, I want to create audit logs in database for all the database changes like(column changed, value changed in column, userid, timestamp and some other fields). I want to create a generalized service which has methods exposed for such operations and I can access them from any other  component in the application. As far as I have read, this can be done through hibernate envers or Spring  AOP. Can you please suggest and provde me with an example which I can utilize to extend it further.

P.S. : I don't want to use trigger based logging for auditing database changes

Suppose this is my entiity stock; I am performing some simple save operations on the stock thru hibernate. Suppose, I have a main method and I perform below mentioned operation

Comment: Unclear question without any sample code as a basis for discussion. Please update the question and be more specific.

Comment: added the code.To be specific; I want to develop a generalized service/component which can be used across different projects to audit log the database changes happening on a table in application. For ex: I want to have some interceptors or something like that which are put on those tables and whenever an operation is performed on that table; the changes are stored in a table. I have achieved this with Hibernate Interceptors but I want to do t through Spring AOP.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am not a Spring or Hibernate user, so I do not know what exactly you need to capture. But if it is just the setters of any `@Entity`-annotated class, the whole thing would basically look like this:

**Driver application:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Maven + Hibernate + MySQL");
//      Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
//      Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        Stock stock = new Stock();
        stock.setStockCode("7000");
        stock.setStockName("z");
//      session.saveOrUpdate(stock);
    }
}
```

**Auditing aspect:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;

@Aspect
public class DBAuditAspect {
    @Before("execution(public void set*(*)) && @target(javax.persistence.Entity) && args(setterArgument)")
    public void entitySetterExecution(Object setterArgument, JoinPoint thisJoinPoint) {
        System.out.println(thisJoinPoint + " - " + setterArgument);
    }
}
```

**Console output:**

```
Maven + Hibernate + MySQL
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Stock.setStockCode(String)) - 7000
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Stock.setStockName(String)) - z
```

The more general question of how to set up and use Spring AOP is explained in the documentation, chapter [9. Aspect Oriented Programming with Spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html).